# How to handle the Connection Reset error?

Tags: java, sockets

When I close the client abruptly without closing the socket. The server will first loop some times and then throw the Connection Reset Exception. Why server will first loop rather than throwing the Exception intermediately?
How to handle the situation where client disconnect the connection without close the socket?
The following is the listenClient method of server:

```
private void listenClientMessage() throws IOException {
            String line = null;
            while (true) {
                try{
                    line = in.readLine();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Client disconect abruptly");
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                if (line.startsWith("\\")) {
                    if (processClientRequest(line)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    broadcast(clientName + ": " + line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Move your try catch block outside the while loop.

Comment: Because TCP/IP connections are not "hard" wired. You don't know for sure that you have lost the connection until you try to send something to the remote pair. So a certain delay is to be expected. You don't need to handle it in another way than a plain old disconnection. PS: ```throw new MyException(_e_)``` is better, you won't loose the original error

Comment: In my code, if client disconnects abruptly, server will broadcast null many times until it catches the exception. I know it is because the server do not sure whether it lost the connection with client. But I do not want to broadcast null many times, so how to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain "broadcast null many times"? You can't know if someone's computer has eg. shutdown abrutly, until you try to send him some bytes (either application data, or protocole data like heartbeat). Since you didn't explain what technologies you are using, I assume it is plain old sockets. So no, you can't handle abrupt disconnection better than assuming he is connected until you try to contact him.